# Format specifier %F missing from glibc's documentation

Tags: c, printf, glibc

I stumbled upon the following deficiency in the [GNU C Library's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.24/html_mono/libc.html#Table-of-Output-Conversions):

> ‘%f’
>
> Print a floating-point number in normal (fixed-point) notation. See Floating-Point Conversions, for details.

And it does not mention `%F` anywhere, although according to the [C99 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1):

> The F conversion specifier produces INF, INFINITY, or NAN instead of inf, infinity, or nan, respectively.

A simple example to test this:

```
double inf = 1.0 / 0.0;
printf( "Testing on %ld.%ld, %%f: %f and %%F: %F.\n", __GLIBC__, __GLIBC_MINOR__, inf, inf );
```

This outputs:

```
Testing on 2.24, %f: inf and %F: INF.
```

So it works as it should, not as the documentation says.

I was thinking why the capital `F` feature is not in the documentation. Does it make sense? Yes. Does it comply with the standard? Yes. Is it be implemented? Yes. So, I don't see the reason.

Is there a convention that issues regulated by the standard are automatically considered part of the library documentation? Is it safe to use `%F` in a printf format?

Comment: @Lundin oooh yes. my point was supposed to be "Yes `F` it is safe as the Standard does document it."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That various open source projects come with incomplete or incorrect documentation isn't exactly news. The documentation is simply missing this information indeed.

The [2.36 documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.36/html_mono/libc.html) is also missing this info. *Conclusion:* the documentation is bad.

And yes `%F` is perfectly safe and well-defined as per C99. For very old compiler versions (such as gcc < 5.0.0) you should compile with `-std=c99` however.

Comment: Then one should notify the maintainers about that.

Comment: @Zakk https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2023-January/144842.html